Find all square idempotent matrices over any field.
I need to find all square idempotent matrices of any size and field. I'm thinking I should start with some facts about diagonalizable $M$'s, but I can't get going. Can anyone provide a starting hint?

can you find all the idempotents of $2 \times 2$ real matrices? What about $3 \times 3$?

For the case where the field is $\mathbb{F_2}$, see here.

I would first group them by rank, and then pick a canonical representative from each group.

For the $2 \times 2$ case, see the answers to this question here.

"of any size and any field" looks a bit "large", don't you think ?
